# Message ordering in a highly available environenment

Tags: architecture, apache-kafka, high-availability

We're building a highly available environment for receiving financial transaction records with online integration endpoints to our system. Our current architecture is to have Kafka producers as the receiver end of these messages and push them into Kafka partitions. Kafka partitions are keyed per customer.

Message ordering is only important per customer. Different customer messages might be out of order and no harm is done. But if A and B are two messages sent from the same customer and if A happened-before B, than I have to be sure A is processed before B by Kafka consumers.

In our current approach we plan to have more than one producers to receive these messages. Let's say P1 and P2. Even if P1 receive the message A before P2 receives B, P2 might write B to Kafka before P1.

The only solution I can think of, having one producer per customer seems to solve the problem. But this is a hit on load balancing and high availability. Plus the problem of routing the messages to producers per customer arises.

My question is, what are the strategies to ensure that if customer sends A before B, A is written to Kafka partition before B?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Kafka. It's all about your upstream systems. You haven't given much details, and you would have to go deep into your upstream architecture, and you'll have some decisions to make. For example, if a customer is using their desktop and their mobile phone at the same time, do you care if those messages are ordered completely, or do you only care if one "channel" is ordered for the customer? With session management, you should be able to do them both individually, but because it is probably two different systems backending them, together might be impossible.

Comment: @DavidGriffin Hi David, sorry if it wasn't clear, our customers in this case are banks and other financial institutions and our integration points are web services (soap and rest). So my only channel is whichever service that customer is using and I only care that one channel is ordered. On the other hand, I was thinking these services as stateless but nothing is decided yet, maybe one of the reasons I couldn't give much detail. We can dictate in our case our customers how they will call us, maybe with some custom headers that might help with routing but I'm a bit lost here.

Comment: I think you just handle it with session management. A customer interacts with a given channel via a single session. At that point, even if you used different producers you could timestamp the request via the session. I mean think about it, one way or the other you have to serialize the customer requests, which means funneling down everything for a customer for a channel into a single stream. Whether that happens upstream in your service routers, or in your middleware via session management, or a combination thereof, it sort of has to happen before it gets to Kafka.

Comment: But I'm creating a single point of failure for that customer, am I not? I guess it's a necessary evil in this situation. Thanks for your comments, I'll look around a little bit before going in this path. This looks interesting: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csliu/2009/05/18/time-and-order-of-events-in-distributed-system

Comment: I think that blog could help with keeping records ordered correctly across all customers. I handle that a different way. I sync my clocks between my client and server. The client application keeps its own concept of "now", based on pings to the server. Client pings server with "now" in milliseconds, server pings back with its version of "now" in milliseconds. Client measures how long the trip took in milliseconds, and uses that to adjust its clock to the serverss. If the roundtrip takes 20 miliseconds, at the absolute worst client and server will be off by 10 milliseconds, more like 2-3.